# An error occurred after hosting of jsp web application

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-hosting

I have created a jsp web application. The real task is i have to host my project in the university server using WINSCP. But when i test the project using the university domain i am  getting this error

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\student\gtalluri\workspace\java\MSUVotingSystem\WebContent\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. edu.msu.isa.jdbc.SQLServer resolves to a package
An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [C:\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\student\gtalluri\workspace\java\MSUVotingSystem\WebContent\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. edu.msu.isa.jdbc.DateStore resolves to a package
An error occurred at line: 108 in the jsp file: /student/gtalluri/workspace/java/MSUVotingSystem/WebContent/index.jsp
SQLServer cannot be resolved**

I am unable to understand what the actual problem is , i tried to change the tomcat settings but this did not solve my problem.

To find the exact error please go to the following link ad guide me what is the exact problem

Comment: The error is what it says- you think you are importing a class, but it is actually a package.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve it

Comment: Don't try to import a package?

Comment: How to do that ... I just imported the project using ftp to the server

Comment: You have code that attempts to import a class. It's not importing a class, it's importing a package, which isn't legal Java. Nobody here knows what classes/libraries you have available, so all we can say is "import the right thing instead of the wrong thing". "Importing" in this case has absolutely nothing to do with how you're *deploying* your app.

Comment: I didn't imported entire package at once in the code, I just imported each class individually

Comment: Apparently not, because one of the things you're importing would appear to be a package, not a class--that's precisely what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I will check the code once again

Comment: The project is perfectly working in localhost, but when i published the project to server it is showing this error

Comment: Then the server doesn't have the same libraries you have?

Comment: The problem is we dont have access to the server right now, i already spoke to my professor and they will give us access soon

Comment: If i set the classpath with my jar file in the server, then will it solve my problem?

Comment: Not even sure what that means. In order to be on the classpath it either has to be in WEB-INF/lib, or shared by the app container. If you're using different versions of the library that'll be an issue, but if you're pushing up a WAR then the library should be included in the WAR.

Comment: I had already included in web-inf/lib ... I think I should set the classpath with the same version in the server

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation issue .According to the log printed I come to know that there is an issue with the Import statement within JSP.

```
<%@ page import="" %>
```

SQLServer.class file is not residing in the package provided in the above import statement.